# `CASE values1 WHEN values2` compare multiple columns, instead of deeply nested `if(values1 = values2)`

Tags: mysql, case

I want to compare system table `points` against a user's input `answer`, and give every specific combination a score, and order by that. The 2 columns to compare into a score are `po.points` and `an.answer`. Both columns can have a value from 1 - 3, so that's 9 different combinations. It will be 0 - 3 soon, so 16 different combinations. Currently, I do this, and that works:

```sql
SELECT if(po.points = 3 and an.answer = 3, 8, if(po.points = 2 and an.answer = 2, 5, if(po.points = 1 and an.answer = 1, 3, if(po.points = 3 and an.answer = 2, -3, if(po.points = 3 and an.answer = 1, -10, if(po.points = 2 and an.answer = 3, 0, if(po.points = 2 and an.answer = 1, -2, if(po.points = 1 and an.answer = 3, -1, 0)))))))) as score
```

What a mess! But that's not so important, because that blob of numbers and ifs is compiled from a configured matrix somewhere else. It doesn't have to be pretty. But it's also LONG, and that's just 9 combinations. With 16 combinations (soon), it's even way worse, and even more `if()` that MySQL has to parse.

So I was thinking `CASE` to the rescue! Look at this readable beauty!:

```sql
SELECT case (po.points, an.answer) when (3, 3) then 8 when (2, 2) then 5 when (1, 1) then 3 when (3, 2) then -3 when (3, 1) then -10 when (2, 3) then 0 when (2, 1) then -2 when (1, 3) then -1 else 0 end as score
```

It's shorter, it's more readable, it's 1 comparing structure instead of separate ifs, it's better in every way, MySQL must love this! But no, MySQL does not love OR accept this:

> Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Alright, fine, maybe I can force them into being 1 column. `CONCAT()` to the rescue! Already it didn't *feel* great anymore, but let's give it a shot anyway:

```sql
SELECT case concat(po.points, '-', an.answer) when concat(3, '-', 3) then 8 when concat(2, '-', 2) then 5 when concat(1, '-', 1) then 3 when concat(3, '-', 2) then -3 when concat(3, '-', 1) then -10 when concat(2, '-', 3) then 0 when concat(2, '-', 1) then -2 when concat(1, '-', 3) then -1 else 0 end as score
```

Not nearly as pretty, not nearly as shot, and now it's just concatting all the numbers in the database. That's gross, and it can't be fast. But it works.

(Actually, it's about the same speed as the 9-if-inception, surprisingly, but I stil hate it.)

Is there a faster way to do the 9-combinations-comparison (will be 16-combination-comparison) that's faster than 9 ifs? There might not be, that's fine too. The results are acceptably fast, and I can't imagine the ifs are the slowdown, but I'm still curious how to do this better.

Comment: can you please provide a full [mre] with create table and insert into a dbfiddle would also be good

Comment: Why not store the points/answer in a seperate table and the result.  Then it's just a table query using indexes which wold be fast instead of a case stement in code...  if needed you could setup a function and have it return the result.  Then if the results or combinations change, you change data and not code.

Comment: why not just `when '3-3' then ...`?  no need to concat hardcoded values.  otherwise, just go with the other form of case, as shown in SelVazi's answer.  don't worry about fast unless you know you have performance issues; nothing like this is likely to have any observable impact, unless it affects whether an index can be used (not the case here).

Comment: (`case points*4+answer when 15 then 8 when 10 then 5 when 5 then 3 when 14 then -3 when 13 then -10 when 11 then 0 when 9 then -2 when 7 then -1 else 0 end as score` is likely to be faster than concat, but again, don't worry about fast enough, go for readability, which that certainly isn't.

Comment: I don't like the "concat" solution. Seems brittle to me and can start failing in the future for some values.

Comment: @xQbert From a table can't be faster than hardcoded. And it would still need a two-column comparison.

Comment: @ysth The hardcoded concat is a good point. I don't know how inefficient the concats are, but the still necessary concat is ran fewer times than the hardcoded, so that might work. I'm trying it.

Comment: @ysth It's prettier, but still slower than the 9 ifs. Surprisingly little slower, but slower. ~ 310 ms vs 290 ms.

Comment: I strongly doubt you will see a repeatable 20 millisecond difference from *any* of the things suggested

Comment: @rudie  The optimizer will likely use the index or do a full table scan depending on # of rows involved.  Eitherway you should be talking about subsecond response time depending on the of rows involved.  If your values can change (whihc it appears they will going from 9 to 16 maybe to 25 or 36 later... I would think changing a table's data is far simplier and efficient and updating a code block; but to each their own.  the "but I'm still curious how to do this better." is subjective do "What" better?  I'd not want to change code so I saw better as avoiding code changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COALESCE(map.score, 0) AS score
FROM po
JOIN an ON ...whatever your join condition is...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  VALUES ROW(3,3,8), ROW(2,2,5), ROW(1,1,3), ROW(3,2,-3), ROW(3,1,-10), ROW(2,3,0), ROW(2,1,-2), ROW(1,3,-1)
) AS map(points, answer, score) ON po.points = map.points AND an.answer = map.answer;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/sRvBdqkH

Or if the mapping values are consistent, you could store your `map` as a real table and join to it.

---

Update to show the persistent table solution:

```
CREATE TABLE scoremap (
  points INT,
  answer INT,
  score INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (points, answer)
);

INSERT INTO scoremap VALUES
(3,3,8), (2,2,5), (1,1,3), (3,2,-3), (3,1,-10), (2,3,0), (2,1,-2), (1,3,-1);

SELECT COALESCE(map.score, 0) AS score
FROM po
JOIN an -- ON ...whatever your join condition is...
LEFT OUTER JOIN scoremap AS map
  ON po.points = map.points AND an.answer = map.answer;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/gVfsA4G4

Comment: That's much slower than the hardcoded ifs. The calculation (or JOIN conditions in this case) is made 500k times. Hardcoded is much faster. I do like the CTE-style temp table without CTE.

Comment: If you need it to be optimized, then create a real table and define its primary key on `(points, answer)`.

Comment: This is what I was thinking.  I can't imagine a response time other than sub second... given proper indexes and the number of rows in an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `CASE` clause as follows :

```
  case
    when po.points = 3 and an.answer = 3  then 8 
    when po.points = 2 and an.answer = 2  then 5
    when po.points = 1 and an.answer = 1  then 3 
    when po.points = 3 and an.answer = 2  then -3 
    when po.points = 3 and an.answer = 1  then -10 
    when po.points = 2 and an.answer = 3  then 0 
    when po.points = 2 and an.answer = 1  then -2 
    when po.points = 1 and an.answer = 3  then -1 
    else 0 
  end as score;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ingnD1hI)

Comment: This one looks like the simplest solution to me. Long but safe.

Comment: That's what the ifs already do. It doesn't have to be readable, just fast. I don't know how mysql's optimizer works, but this seems the same as the 9 ifs.